# Why is select element behaving weirdly on Blazor with data binding?

Tags: html, blazor

I have a Blazor app.

If I add a select element like so:

```
<select multiple name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

all is well. It displays a simple list box and I can multiple select.

Now I add this variable:

```
private string[] m_otherClients = {"Volvo", "Saab", "Open", "Audi"};
```

And I alter the declaration of the select like so:

```
<select multiple @bind="m_otherClients" name="cars" id="cars">
    @if (m_otherClients != null)
    {
        @foreach (var cnt in m_otherClients)
        {
            <option value="@cnt">@cnt</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Now the listbox displays but with all items highlighted and when I click on one of them m_otherClients changes it's value and now contains only the item I clicked on, and so the UI updates and now the listbox has only this item in it.

How can I prevent the clicking on the select from altering the value of m_otherClients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, when you use `@bind="m_otherClients"` with the `<select>` element, you're binding the selected values directly to the `m_otherClients` array. This is why when you click an option in the select box, it changes the value of `m_otherClients` to just the clicked option.

If you want to prevent the `m_otherClients` array from changing when an option is clicked, you should not use `@bind` for this specific `<select>` element. Instead, you can handle the selection manually using JavaScript and update the selected items without affecting the underlying data source. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```cs
<select multiple name="cars" id="cars">
    @foreach (var cnt in m_otherClients)
    {
        <option value="@cnt" selected="@m_otherClients.Contains(cnt)" @onchange="ToggleSelection">@cnt</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    private string[] m_otherClients = { "Volvo", "Saab", "Open", "Audi" };

    private void ToggleSelection(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedValue = e.Value.ToString();
        if (m_otherClients.Contains(selectedValue))
        {
            m_otherClients = m_otherClients.Where(item => item != selectedValue).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            m_otherClients = m_otherClients.Concat(new[] { selectedValue }).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, we are manually handling the selection and deselection of options in the `<select>` element. The `ToggleSelection` method is called when an option is changed (clicked), and it updates the `m_otherClients` array accordingly. This way, the array won't change unless you explicitly modify it, and the UI will reflect the selected items as you toggle them.

Comment: I noticed one thing. If I put a breakpoint in ToggleSelection on the line var selectedValue = e.Value.ToString();, then when I select an item in the list this breakpoint is not hit? Might you know why?

Comment: ok, if I add the @onchange hook to the 'select' rather than the 'option', then it is called.